# Call to vote: Synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I have found synonyms to all these tags, please vote up or down if you are eligible on to do so (2000 rep), 4 votes creates the association -2 votes kills it.

[bittorrent](https://superuser.com/tags/bittorrent/synonyms)
[colors](https://superuser.com/tags/colors/synonyms)
[shell-script](https://superuser.com/tags/shell-script/synonyms)
[virtual-machine](https://superuser.com/tags/virtual-machine/synonyms)
[networking](https://superuser.com/tags/networking/synonyms)
[wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/tags/wireless-networking/synonyms)
[operating-systems](https://superuser.com/tags/operating-systems/synonyms)
[mac](https://superuser.com/tags/mac/synonyms)
[memory](https://superuser.com/tags/memory/synonyms) (not sure about this)
[microsoft-access](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-access/synonyms)
[hard-drive](https://superuser.com/tags/hard-drive/synonyms)
[applications](https://superuser.com/tags/applications/synonyms)
[graphics-card](https://superuser.com/tags/graphics-card/synonyms)
[freeze](https://superuser.com/tags/freeze/synonyms)

---

[defragmentation](https://superuser.com/tags/defragmentation/synonyms)

---

Or go to the [full list of synonyms](https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) and see all synonyms to vote on.

Comment: Done my bit ∆ ∆ ∆

Comment: The other option is to visit the [full list of "suggested" synonyms](http://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) to see everything, and vote away. Also, I've added my votes as I feel appropriate to these, and anything else that was on the list.

Comment: @DMA57361 - Good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have merged most of these. The one's that aren't merged and approved are one's with negative votes and I would prefer the community to confirm. Most of the others had enough votes to justify merging.